# how to define variable and change css based on it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

im trying to reset css based on mysql query results and i can get it to work to some extent using an IF{}  else{} statement.

I am trying to find a way to define a number in response where the number can be anywhere from 1-120 and if it is present in response change cell where that number is present if it is present in response change cell to default class.

e.g.

```
Json_encode =   
[{"beacon":"84","location":"YELLOW","date":"2018-04-16","counter":"6","delivery_avg":"00.14"}]

response =
0: {beacon: "68", location: "YELLOW", date: "2018-04-16", counter: "2", delivery_avg: "00.01"}length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

but the beacon as stated above is anything from 1-120 so my example code would be

```
function(changetable)
if (response.contains (number))
return $('td.(item.beacon)').css({'background-color: 'colorof location', border-color: red}
else if (response doesn't contain number)
    return $('td.(item.beacon)').css({'background-color: 'grey', border-color: black}
```

e.g.

```
{beacon: "68", location: "YELLOW", date: "2018-04-16", counter: "2", delivery_avg: "00.01"}
{beacon: "50", location: "YELLOW", date: "2018-04-16", counter: "2", delivery_avg: "00.01"}
{beacon: "30", location: "YELLOW", date: "2018-04-16", counter: "2", delivery_avg: "00.01"}
```

turn cells 68/50/30 background color to yellow

```
{beacon: "50", location: "YELLOW", date: "2018-04-16", counter: "2", delivery_avg: "00.01"}
{beacon: "30", location: "YELLOW", date: "2018-04-16", counter: "2", delivery_avg: "00.01"}
```

68 is not longer showing in response change background color grey

the 1st bit i can seem to do fine the issue im having is changing the color back to grey background and the border to black due to not having the number in response to reference?

```
function updateTable() {
    $('td.coloured').css({'background-color':'#8F8F8F','border-color':'black','border-width':'thin'}).toggleClass('coloured');
    $.get('php/test2.php', function(response) {
  console.log(response, );
    $.each(response, function(index, item) {
      $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'background-color':item.location,'border-color':'black','border-width':'thin'}).addClass('coloured');
         $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'background-color':item.location,'border-color':'black','border-width':'thin'}).addClass('coloured');
      if (item.delivery_avg <= 4.00) {
        return $('td.coloured').css({'border-color': 'lime','border-width': 'thick'}).toggleClass('coloured');
      } else if (item.delivery_avg >= 4.01 && item.delivery_avg <= 7.00) {
        return $('td.coloured').css({'border-color': 'orange','border-width': 'thick'}).toggleClass('coloured');
      } else if (item.delivery_avg >= 7.01 && item.delivery_avg <= 10.00) {
        return $('td.coloured').css({'border-color': 'pink','border-width': 'thick'}).toggleClass('coloured');
      } else if (item.delivery_avg >= 10.01) {
        return $('td.coloured').css({'border-color': 'red','border-width': 'thick'}).toggleClass('coloured');
      } else {
    $('td').css({'background-color':'#8F8F8F','border-color':'black','border-width':'thin'}).addClass('def');

    }
    });

   });
 }
 var updateTableInterval = setInterval(updateTable, 1000);
});
```

PHP

```
$sql = "SELECT
beacon.beacon,
beacon.location,
beacon.date,
beacon.counter,
del.delivery_avg
FROM
(
SELECT
    beacon,
    location,
    date,
    COUNT(location) AS counter
FROM `test`.`test`
WHERE `date` = CURDATE()
AND `time` > ( NOW() - INTERVAL 10 SECOND )
GROUP BY beacon
) beacon
JOIN
(
SELECT
    beacon,
    TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(MAX(`time`), MIN(`time`)), '%i.%s') AS delivery_avg
FROM `test`.`test`
WHERE date = CURDATE()
AND time > ( NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE )
GROUP BY beacon
) 
del ON beacon.beacon = del.beacon
GROUP BY beacon.counter DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


$result = mysqli_query($conn ,  $sql);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: That's not an Object in `.css()`. By the way, I don't think jQuery accepts the French version of `color`.

Comment: Can you show us your markup, or even better, a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example? Your response doesn't look like valid JSON to me.

Comment: I have added in my actual function and my php

Comment: @PHPglue “colour” is British English, but still CSS will not parse that…